# Dimensionality of a function space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a finite set belonging to the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, and consider the product set $\mathcal{S}^k$ for some positive integer $k \geq 2$, i.e., $\mathcal{S}^k = \{\underline{s} \in \mathbb{N}^k \,|\, \underline{s}_i \in \mathcal{S}, \forall 1 \leq i \leq k\}$. Then consider the set $\mathcal{F}$ of real-valued functions over $\mathcal{S}^k$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \{f \,|\, f: \mathcal{S}^k \to \mathbb{R} \}.
\end{equation} 
Let $S$ be the cardinality of $\mathcal{S}$. My question is: Is the "dimension" of $\mathcal{F}$ equal to $S^k$ or infinite-dimensional? Also, is there a "natural" way to introduce an inner product and a basis in this setting? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of your space (as a vector space over $\Bbb R$) is $ S^k.$  There's a natural basis $B$ for $\mathcal F: B= \{ f: \mathcal S^k \to \Bbb R \vert f(p) =1 \text{ for some } p \in \mathcal S, 0 \text{ otherwise}\}.$  I'll leave it to you to show that $B$ is linearly independent and spans $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post. So I guess you defined the inner product $<f,g> = \sum_{\underline{s} \in \mathcal{S}^k} f(\underline{s}) g(\underline{s})$ so that the basis $B$ is orthonormal. It also spans $\mathcal{F}$ because we can use $f(\underline{p})$ as the "coefficient" of some basis function when it is $1$ at $\underline{p}$.

Comment: Since any orthonormal set of functions is linear independent, yes. Given the cardinality is still finite.

Comment: Yes, you can use that to define an inner product.  And both upvotes and acceptances for answers that you find useful are always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think $S$ is isomorphic to $\{1,2,...,|S|\}$, so S^k is isomorphic to $\{1,2,...,|S|\}^k$ which is isomorphic to $\{1,..., |S|\cdot k\}$. So basically you have $\{f \mid f  : \{1,..., |S|\cdot k\} \to \mathbb{R} \}$. So a function $f$ is really nothing else then a $|S|\cdot k$-tuple of real numbers, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{|S|\cdot k}$.